# Sync-Unicorn' errored "Cannot read property '0' of undefined at unicorn.js" error while setting up Habitat

Tags: habitat, unicorn

I am setting up habitat and I was going to [installation instructions](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started). When I run “default” task from Visual Studio 2015 Task Runner Explorer, I get the following error.

> 00:04:18] '05-Sync-Unicorn' errored after 25 ms[00:04:18] TypeError:
>   Cannot read property '0' of undefined    at
>   C:\Projects\Habitat\scripts\unicorn.js:25:98    at Parser.
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:489:18)    at
>   emitOne (events.js:77:13)    at Parser.emit (events.js:169:7)    at
>   Object.onclosetag
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:447:26)    at
>   emit
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:640:35)
>   at emitNode
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:645:5)
>   at closeTag
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:905:7)
>   at Object.write
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1452:13)
>   at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:508:31)
>   [00:04:18] 'default' errored after 2.12 min[00:04:18] TypeError in
>   plugin 'run-sequence(05-Sync-Unicorn)'Message:    Cannot read property
>   '0' of undefinedStack:TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>   at C:\Projects\Habitat\scripts\unicorn.js:25:98    at
>   Parser.
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:489:18)    at
>   emitOne (events.js:77:13)    at Parser.emit (events.js:169:7)    at
>   Object.onclosetag
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:447:26)    at
>   emit
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:640:35)
>   at emitNode
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:645:5)
>   at closeTag
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:905:7)
>   at Object.write
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1452:13)
>   at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString
>   (C:\Projects\Habitat\node_modules\xml2js\lib\xml2js.js:508:31)Process
>   terminated with code 1.

Can someone help? Am I missing something?

If I go to unicorn.aspx and try to run Unicorn "Sync" on each project I get an error at http://habitat.dev.local/unicorn.aspx?verb=Sync&configuration=Foundation.Forms&log=Debug

> [A] master:/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Modules/Web Forms for
>   Marketers/Mvc Form (f2cca16d-7524-4e99-8ee0-78ff6394a3b3) 2 errors
>   occurred during deserialization. Earlier log messages for items below
>   should be ignored; an error occurred that was retried and failed to
>   correct.master:/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for
>   Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Register an Outcome
>   (90538392-5648-4326-b506-e1913ed1daa8)C:\projects\Habitat\src\Foundation\forms\serialization\Foundation.Forms.WffmActions.RegisterOutcome\Register
>   an Outcome.yml> ParentItemNotFoundException: Exception of type
>   'Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Exceptions.ParentItemNotFoundException'
>   was thrown.master:/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Modules/Web Forms for
>   Marketers/Mvc Form
>   (f2cca16d-7524-4e99-8ee0-78ff6394a3b3)C:\projects\Habitat\src\Foundation\forms\serialization\Foundation.Forms.Renderings.MvcForm\Mvc
>   Form.yml> ParentItemNotFoundException: Exception of type
>   'Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Exceptions.ParentItemNotFoundException'
>   was thrown. For full stack traces of each exception, see the Sitecore
>   logs.

Thanks,
Gowtham.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say that you "try to run each project"?

Comment: Do you have Webforms for Marketers installed? from the second error, it looks like it can't find certain files it expects from the module.

Comment: Zachary, I mean, when I go to unicorn.aspx and run unicorn sync for each project

Comment: Pat, I do have Webforms for Marketers installed. I just cloned the repo, I can I miss files?

Comment: @GowthamreddyTirumalareddy I think you should install WFFM module by yourself and run sync after that

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: @AndreyBobrov, I added the WFFM module again and ran the "Default" task again. Still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that unicorn sync can't find your Shared key.

### Does the config file exist in your website.

Please make sure this file is deployed in your website. It should be located at `[Your Web Path]/App_config/Include/Unicorn/Unicorn.UI.config`

https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/efa05353abd956c58cfa269541a2a848dc55e356/src/Foundation/Serialization/code/App_Config/Include/Unicorn/Unicorn.UI.config#L17

```
    <authenticationProvider type="Unicorn.ControlPanel.Security.ChapAuthenticationProvider, Unicorn">
       <SharedSecret>749CABBC85EAD20CE55E2C6066F1BE375D2115696C8A8B24DB6ED1FD60613086</SharedSecret>
       <!-- Authentication challenges are stored in a Sitecore database. You can select which database here. No item installs/templates are required. -->
       <ChallengeDatabase>web</ChallengeDatabase>
       <!-- 
        Writes the reason why failed automated tool authentications failed to the Sitecore logs.
        Will result in writing your shared secret to the logs as part of the signature base, so you can disable it if you wish.
       -->
       <WriteAuthFailuresToLog>false</WriteAuthFailuresToLog>
    </authenticationProvider>
```

### Is your gulp config set to your site location

You need to make sure a few setting are3 right. In the `gulp-config.js` in the root of the project, make sure `instanceRoot` and `websiteRoot` are properly set.
https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/78f9b95d133424b30e4d4ecfc2b1c7e1c53be07f/gulp-config.js

```
var instanceRoot = "C:\\websites\\Habitat.dev.local";
var config = {
websiteRoot: instanceRoot + "\\Website",
sitecoreLibraries: instanceRoot + "\\Website\\bin",
licensePath: instanceRoot + "\\Data\\license.xml",
solutionName: "Habitat",
buildConfiguration: "Debug",
runCleanBuilds: false
};
```

### Gulp file looks for your config

In the gulpfile.js (the gulp task) is specifically looks for the config file with the shared key with the js configs set above.
https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/78f9b95d133424b30e4d4ecfc2b1c7e1c53be07f/gulpfile.js#L84

You can see below that it is specifically looking for the config file.
`options.authenticationConfigFile = config.websiteRoot + "/App_config/Include/Unicorn/Unicorn.UI.config";`

### Where your error is

Your error is here and it tries to parse the config file
https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/efa05353abd956c58cfa269541a2a848dc55e356/scripts/unicorn.js#L25

`secret = result.configuration.sitecore[0].unicorn[0].authenticationProvider[0].SharedSecret[0];`

Comment: I made sure that I have the unicorn config file in the location, made sure gulp config is pointing to sight website root and I still get struck on unicorn sync.

Comment: actually now it just freezes at sync step . Scipt doesn't move from [20:22:03] Starting '05-Sync-Unicorn'...

Comment: It spits out the unicorn log while it is running. Any errors in the console?

Comment: no, I do not see anything. I added the following logs to gulp.task("05-Sync-Unicorn", function (callback) to check if the "options" are right and they are going to right locations.   util.log("options.siteHostName: " + options.siteHostName);
  util.log("options.authenticationConfigFile: " + options.authenticationConfigFile);

Comment: This is what happens C:\projects\Habitat> cmd.exe /c gulp -b "C:\projects\Habitat" --color --gulpfile "C:\projects\Habitat\Gulpfile.js" 05-Sync-Unicorn
[23:44:48] Using gulpfile C:\projects\Habitat\Gulpfile.js
[23:44:48] Starting '05-Sync-Unicorn'...
[23:44:48] options.siteHostName: http://habitat.dev.local
[23:44:48] options.authenticationConfigFile: C:\websites\Habitat.dev.local\Website\App_config\Include\Unicorn\Unicorn.UI.config

It just sits there

Answer (score 0):

You should make the Sitecore variable below in **z.Habitat.DevSettings.config** correct at your machine

```
<sc.variable name="sourceFolder" value="C:\projects\Habitat\src" />
```

Comment: Yup. I have the correct location